# php interpretation stops at > sign

Tags: php

I'm trying to install a site locally. Using XAMPP 3.2.3 and php 5.6.

I have an index2.php file which looks like this:

```
<? 
        if (2>1)
        {
            echo 'aa';
        }
```

I open http://localhost/index2.php and see:

```
1) { echo 'aa'; }
```

somehow the ">" is interpreted as the end of the php code. How can I make it interpret '>" signs in condition expressions properly? I.e. so the output is

```
aa
```

Comment: Why are you using PHP 5?

Comment: @Dai, because the original site is working on php 5. This is not my decision to make.

Comment: @klm123 Then you should fire your client or make them agree to update their site.

Comment: Shouldn't `<?` actually be `<?php`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You need to use `<?php`, not `<?`, as your script block start.
- `<?` is an XML *thing*, not a PHP *thing*.
- The `<?=` syntax is shorthand for `<?php echo` and is always legal.
- But the `<?` syntax (without the `=`) is only supported when `short_open_tag` (in `php.ini`) is enabled, but this is an **obsolete** option that is no-longer supported.

Comment: yes. change of the short_open_tag setting has fixed the problem!